# ArangoDB Oasis ETIMEDOUT

Tags: database, arangodb, oasis

We're currently evaluating ArangoDB Oasis with two deployments.  Both have a database with a collection of mock sensor data that has been filled with over 75,000,000 documents.  When we attempt to query the collection with an aggregation window, we are getting ETIMEDOUT errors with the JavaScript driver more often than we would like.  Normally, the query only takes a few milliseconds (30-40ms) with a stream cursor, but when the timeout happens, it takes around 130000ms to recover.  Arango recently switched us to a different load balancer, which seemed to help slightly, but didn't eliminate the problem.  We haven't had any ETIMEDOUT errors when working with a local Docker container image of Arango.  Our Oasis deployments and our test environment are both hosted in the same region on AWS.

Has anyone else had problems with ETIMEDOUT errors?  If so, were you able to solve them?